# Read out Internet call settings (SIP Account)

Tags: android, sip, account

I'm working on an Android application which can make internet phone calls. I got everything working, from registering with the SIP server and making calls, updating real time status, etc. But the SIP account I use for the application has been set in the codes. And thats not what I want.

In android 2.3.1 + there is a menu in: Settings>calls>Internet call settings

In "Internet call settings" you're able to set some settings for internet calling, you can also add an SIP account there.

So what do I want? I want to read out the SIP account thats been set in that menu. Does anyone know if it's possible or not? if so, any help would be appreciated. From a link with a tutorial for this or someone that encoutered something like this before and is able and willing to help me.

Thanks, :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support by android for reading SIP account list programmatic.

For more detail you can refer **[android.net.sip.SipManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html)**

Comment: Please add more information to your answer. For trivial answers please use comments.